# WIX - Burn Install condition is not being set in options dialog

Tags: wix, wix3.9

I have modified the RtfLicense theme to include a checkbox on the options dialog. The name of the checkbox is the same name as the variable name that I use in the install condition. When I execute the bundle and check the checkbox the variable is always false.

bundle.was...

```
<Variable Name="INSTALLSERVER" />

    <Chain>
      <ExePackage Cache="no" 
                  InstallCondition="INSTALLSERVER" 
                  Description="SQL Server and Server Bundle" 
                  Id="Server" 
                  SourceFile="ServerSQLBundle.exe">
      </ExePackage>
```

RtfTheme.xml....

```
<Page Name="Options">
        <Text X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.OptionsHeader)</Text>
        <Text X="11" Y="120" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="3" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.OptionsDescription)</Text>
        <Checkbox Name="INSTALLSERVER" X="11" Y="166" Width="260" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3">Install Server</Checkbox>
       <Button Name="OptionsOkButton" X="229" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.OptionsOkButton)</Button>
      <Button Name="InstallButton" X="314" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallInstallButton)</Button>
      <Button Name="WelcomeCancelButton" X="404" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallCloseButton)</Button>
    </Page>
```

Why is the variable not getting set?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Burn expert, but I think you need to "persist" your variable to pass it along to the chain package E.g `<Variable Name="INSTALLSERVER" Type="numeric" Value="1"  Persisted="yes" bal:Overridable="yes"  />`